# android image button background, source and selector

Tags: android, android-selector, android-imagebutton

I've got some imagebuttons (about 15) with different backgrounds and sources. I want to change the pressed state of all of them on the same way: adding a color overlay.

Is there a way without onTouchListern (all examples I tried didn't work correctly...) and without a separat active-image and selector.xml for each button, like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_one_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_one"/>

</selector>
```

ImageButton (current state):

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_one_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_one_description"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_two" />
```

Source is set in Java with `setImageResource` or `setImageBitmap`

Comment: Have you try `OnClickListener` settings instead of `onTouchListener`? Or both of them sound the same for you.

Comment: adding `ib.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);` on start of my onClick-Method and `ib.clearColorFilter();` on the end didn't do anything. I'll add an example of my ImageButtons.

Answer (score 2):

In java code, for the onClicklisteners of the buttons add,

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed_image);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's better than a lot of selector.xml, but I want to overlay a color on the background image without needing extra _pressed_images (:

Comment: oh, and then I have to replace the pressed_image by the normal one... where?

Comment: In the onclick method of the buttons. Overlay can also be added if you want.

Comment: yeah, I want, but how? :D